# React Native maps drawing directions

Tags: android, react-native

I found so much solutions for using Gmaps (maps, markers, animations, geolocation) in React Native app. But I can't found any guides to using Gmaps Directions. 
How can i used Google maps Directions API and drawing direction on map with React Native? Can i solve this problem by default MapView, or need custom package?

Answer (score 6):

We need to draw directions using Mapview.Polyline component from airbnb.
TO draw the the polyline, we need to get coordinates of route between two locations, which we can get by making API calls as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsRequests
then getting JSON object by making API calls from which we should use overview_polyline string and decode it to get list of LatLang objects and pass it as prop to Mapview.Polyline to get the route displayed on map.

Sample API call 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Insert your google API key in the url

Answer (score 2):

Be careful of incorporating navigation into your app via GoogleMaps APIs as it may be in violation of Google's Terms & Conditions. We ran into this recently.

Here is the link [Google Maps API T&Cs](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)

Check out 10.4.c.iii "No Navigation"

I might be reading it or understanding it incorrectly, but I took it to mean do not use the API to navigate.

Comment: Good call, but I believe it only is valid for actual navigation scenarious like turn-by-turn navigation etc. Just showing directions (a polyline representing the overview of how to go from A to B) on the map should be fine.

Comment: @riper Isn't an A-B polyline considered "route guidance"? I find it slightly bizarre that Google provides a public Directions API but prohibits its use for route assistance.